How to debug Serilog to MySQL connection issues?
I'm new to Serilog and SO and I'm trying to use Serilog to log into a MySql 5.7 database.
I'm getting this error from the MySql server, for which I couldn't find any help online:
Aborted connection 23 to db: 'serilog' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets) For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://www.mysql.com.
I have set up a Visual Studio 2022 .NET 7 Console App using Serilog.Sinks.MySQL (5.0.0).
This is the test code:
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

using var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MySQL("server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=***;database=serilog", "serilog", Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Verbose)
    .CreateLogger();

log.Information("hello, serilog");


The connection string works in another project in an EF core DB context on the same machine.
The debug console says:
2024-05-22T12:06:27.2690920Z Halting sink...
2024-05-22T12:06:27.2724566Z Sending batch of 1 logs
2024-05-22T12:06:27.3249267Z Sink halted successfully.


The database table 'serilog' was created, but no log entries get added to the table.
How would I best dig into the nature of the connection error? Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
